# Does creating a new thread prevent the CPU from utilising the thread's resources for other purposes?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, thread-sleep

If I create a thread to execute a task asynchronously, and within this thread I need to wait on some other event, is there a difference between calling Thread.sleep() for 1 second and creating a timer object to check back in one second to wait for this event? Is the thread reserved from being utilised by the CPU by creating a new thread? If that's the case, is there any difference between these two implementations? Or is the CPU free to utilise the resources of the thread until the timer resumes operations?

edit:
By resources I'm referring to cache, but also the processing power of the cpu itself as a resource. Can the cpu go and do other things when you are waiting on a timer within a thread? I know that doing thread.sleep pauses the thread, but if there are no other operations occuring within the thread, is there any difference between thread.sleep() and creating a timer within that thread? Does the operating system give the thread to other processes while waiting on the timer or is it reserved?

Comment: Pausing your thread frees up the CPU to use the CORE it was running on and cache memory it was consuming for other purposes.  Don't understand what you mean by "utilise the resources of the thread."  That thread is paused, what it's doing is waiting to unpause.  It's not going to start doing something else, but the physical resources it was consuming while running are available for other things.

Comment: By resources I'm referring to cache, but also the processing power of the cpu itself as a resource. Can the cpu go and do other things when you are waiting on a timer within a thread? I know that doing thread.sleep pauses the thread, but if there are no other operations occuring within the thread, is there any difference between thread.sleep() and creating a timer within that thread? Does the operating system give the thread to other processes while waiting on the timer or is it reserved?

Comment: "Waiting on a timer" has no definition.  There is no 'block until next execution' method on java.util.Timer that you can call from inside the current thread.  You need to program your thread to do *SOMETHING* while waiting for the timer to detect the state you're trying to observe.  If you program it to wait in an orderly fashion then the resources it was consuming will be free.  If you write `while(true){didTimerRun();}` probably not so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion that I had was that Thread.Sleep() is not blocking like I assumed. My question was probably hard to comprehend because of this.

My experience with Arduino was that when I called sleep, this would block all execution. Often, much better was to create a timer and return later. In Java, Thread.sleep() is not the same as

```
While(currentTime < (startTime + miliseconds) {
  //do nothing
}
```

Thread.sleep() allows the core of the CPU to continue on doing other operations.

Creating a new thread just creates a block of code that the processor will carry out in a chronological order that is independent from the current thread of execution. It doesn't reserve anything from the CPU. It's only when the CPU becomes unable to carry out all the requested threads at once that problems occur.

Comment: (It does also reserve the stack memory, not just 'create the block of code'.  Which is a negligible amount for regular application programming but memory consumed by thread stacks can be a limiting factor to consider on things like web servers.)

Comment: Right, reserving stack memory is entailed by the fact that there's machine code instructions that are derived from that code within the thread. It's relevant information to point out, however.